# Trying to set root element to SynchronousMode but says does not exist in xaml namespace

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, asynchronous

I am trying to load a loose xaml using LoadAsync method 
but in xaml file when setting the root element to x:SynchronousMode="Async"
it complains. It says SynchronousMode does not exist in xaml namespace

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"  x:SynchronousMode="Async" >
    <Grid>
    <Button x:Name="okButton" x:FieldModifier="public" >OK</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: complaints in runtime or only in design time ?

Comment: There's almost nothing in that window, why would you want to use loadasync? You realise it's not like a conventional async method? Everything is done on the ui thread anyhow, just in chunks. Or one chunk in the case of your markup there.

Comment: @Muds It is design time.

Comment: runtime should be ok, have u tried ?

Comment: @Muds runtime is ok but LoadAsync method does not find any child element when I use the FindName("okButton"). But when I remove the SynchoronousMode from xaml and rerun the program. It find the child element and does not return null handle for okButton. When it finds it LoadAsync method is running synchronously.